# Passing data from two activities to a third

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have total 3 activites. I pass the data from the first activity like this:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), History.class);
        i.putExtra("day", mDay);
        i.putExtra("month", mMonth+1);
        i.putExtra("year", mYear);
        startActivity(i);
```

get the data:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if(extras !=null) { .......
```

now I pass the data from the second activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), History.class);
                i.putExtra("Hday", mDay);
                i.putExtra("Hmonth", mMonth);
                i.putExtra("Hyear", mYear);
                startActivity(i);
```

and get the data from the second activity:

```
Bundle extras2 = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if(extras2 !=null) {
```

So, I have extras to get the data from the first activity, and extras2 to get the data from the second activity. But when I pass the data from any activity both extras are not null!
What have I done wrong?

Comment: so both getExtras() are called within the third activity?  Can I see how the code all fits together for the third activity?

Comment: yes both , extras and extras2 are on the third activity but when i run the program both extras try to retrieve data but only one activity has data to send not both

Comment: Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //items from first activity
    if(extras !=null) {
        day = extras.getInt("day");
        month = extras.getInt("month");
        year = extras.getInt("year");
       }

Bundle extras2 = .getExtras(); //items from second activity
    if(extras2 !=null) {
        day = extras2.getInt("Hday");
        month = extras2.getInt("Hmonth");
        year = extras2.getInt("Hyear");
}  //thats the code (i cant answer my question :/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your third activity has no way of knowing which activity sent the bundle.  You need to add a field that identifies what type of bundle this is so you can process accordingly.  For instance, in activity 1:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), History.class);
        i.putExtra("activity", (int)1);
        i.putExtra("day", mDay);
        i.putExtra("month", mMonth+1);
        i.putExtra("year", mYear);
        startActivity(i);
```

Then in 3rd activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if(extras !=null) { 
       int typeAct = extras.getInt("activity");
       if (typeAct == 1) {
.......
```

Comment: Glad to help and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Don't forget to check the answer that worked best for you :)

Answer (score 0):

pass the data in a one bundle

the first activity would for example have three values in the bundle then the second one retrieves the data from the bundle and `adds`or 'Append' to the second activity and finally in the third activity you can retrieve the data as a single bundle from the second activity.

Comment: i dont pretty much understand what you're saying, what i want to do is to pass data from activity1 & activity2 to activity 3...